# Clean up MongoDB collection before writing results with mongo-hadoop connector in Apache Spark job

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I am writing RDD into MongoDB collection using mongo-hadoop connector like described in [this](https://github.com/plaa/mongo-spark) example

Everything works fine. The results are added into the collection.

But I wonder is there a way to clean up collection before performing save? I did not found any mentions in the mongo-hadoop documentation so it is possible that such feature is not available yet.

Then I would like to ask some tips, is there a better way then initializing MongoClient and run remove query manually inside the Apache Spark job?

Comment: You can use any mongoDb driver in your code to drop schema. After all, it's just a java code which executes on master node.

Answer (score 1):

To cleanup any db or collection use the normal MongoDB connector for that language.

Suppose you are using Spark with Scala

You can use Casbah / Java MongoDB Driver and clear the collection before doing so.

Hadoop Connector is for Read and Write in Bulk Operation.